# How to bind a tooltip effect on a Control instance like Zoom?

Tags: tooltip, leaflet, controls

How can I bind a tooltip effect on a Control instance like Zoom?

Leaflet supports Layers to bind L.Tooltip effect, but  want bind a L.Tooltip to my custom L.Control element.

Comment: Have you seen the Leaflet.draw plugin?  They bind tooltips to their drawing controls.  Maybe look that their source code: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw.  Inside `L.Toolbar._createButton`, they set `link.innerHTML` and `link.title`; I think this is how they have different tooltips on mouseover or click.